Graphs of arbitrary girth having two disjoint spanning trees
For any $g$, does there exist a graph of girth $g$ having two disjoint spanning trees? Up to girth five, such graphs exist, for example the Robertson graph [1]. However, generalizing it to higher girth does not seem trivial.
As a particular case (if more appealing), does there exist 4-regular cage graphs of arbitrary girth which have this property?
[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robertson_graph

Constructions of $4$-regular cage graphs of arbitrary girth with this property might be very hard to find, because constructions of $4$-regular cage graphs of arbitrary girth are hard to find!

@MathieuRundström: I will likely accept the answer by Misha, which answers the question. But if you can provide an explicit construction without taking much of your time, this is very welcome; such constructions may be more informative than random graphs, and presumably use less vertices for reaching the same goal.

@MathieuRundström: cycles are $2$-edge connected, but they do not admit two edge-disjoint spanning trees. Am I missing something?

@ArnaudCasteigts I meant 4-edge connected, my apologies.

As $n \to \infty$, a uniformly random $4$-regular graph on $n$ vertices will have two disjoint spanning trees with probability tending to $1$; also, for any $g$, it will have girth $g$ with probability tending to a positive constant. Therefore, if $n$ is sufficiently large, random $4$-regular graphs will give examples of this.
For the first claim, see Kim and Wormald's Random Matchings Which Induce Hamilton Cycles and Hamiltonian Decompositions of Random Regular Graphs. This actually proves the stronger statement that a random $4$-regular graph decomposes into two disjoint Hamiltonian cycles with high probability - so it has two disjoint spanning trees which are Hamiltonian paths!
For the second claim, see Short Cycles in Random Regular Graphs by McKay, Wormald, and Wysocka. The short summary is that the probability that a random $4$-regular graph has no $k$-cycles (for any constant $k$) tends to $e^{-3^k/(2k)}$ as $n \to \infty$, and that these are asymptotically independent. So the probability that the graph has girth exactly $g$ tends to $$\exp\left(-\frac{3^3}{6} - \frac{3^4}{8} - \frac{3^5}{10} - \dots - \frac{3^{g-1}}{2g-2}\right) \cdot \left(1 - \exp\left(-\frac{3^g}{2g}\right)\right)$$ as $n \to \infty$.

The following is a proof that graphs of arbitrarily large girth and disjoint spanning trees exist.
The following is a result of Tutte and Nash-Williams:

Every $2k$-edge-connected graph has $k$ edge-disjoint spanning trees.

Hence, to find graphs of large girth with many disjoint spanning trees, it suffices to find graphs of large girth and large edge-connectivity. The existence of such graphs follow from theorems of Mader and Tutte. The following is a theorem due to Mader:

If $G$ is a graph of minimum degree $\delta(G)\geq 4k$, then $G$ contains a $k$-connected subgraph.

Since vertex-connectivity is a lower bound on edge-connectivity, the above implies the existence of a $k$-edge-connected subgraph. Tutte proved:

For all $l, g\geq 3$, there exists an $l$-regular graph of girth $g$.

Now, let $l=8k$. By Tutte, there exists an $8k$-regular graph $G$ of girth $g$. By Mader, $G$ has a subgraph $H$ which is $2k$-connected, and hence, has $k$ disjoint spanning trees. $H$ has girth at least $g$ since girth is monotone under subgraphs. If you want $H$ to have girth exactly $g$, take $G$ instead to have girth $2g$, and add an edge in $H$ to form a cycle of length $g$. The case $k=1$ is the one you care about, in which case the graph is a subgraph of an $8$-regular graph.
If I recall correctly, the proof of Tutte's theorem is constructive, but the graphs have $O(l^g)$ vertices. Finding a subgraph such as in Mader's theorem can be done by exhaustive search, so this entire argument gives a constructive proof, though likely algorithmically useless in practice.
